# Import Excel Data programmatically to access table with column mapping

Tags: ms-access, vba, excel

I am in search of a tool / VBA code snippet that can port my excel data to my access table with effective columns mapping. Anybody please share if you have any idea on these.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I'd like to have this too. My team makes imports every day from various sources -- different formats but mostly standard data. The data is not stable enough to support an Access Import Specification, so I want human-guided fuzzy mapping and declaration.  It should look like the common wizard for migrating contact information to a new app, where 'Source.ZIP' is already matched with 'Target.ZIP' and 'NameLast' is ready to be matched with 'Last Name'.

Answer (score 3):

The standard way to import or link Excel in Access is to use the [TransferSpreadsheet method of the DoCmd object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb214134%28v=office.12%29.aspx). The link is for 2007, but it has been available certainly since 2000, if not before. TransferSpreadsheet includes a `HasFieldNames` argument.

Comment: TransferSpreadsheet/TransferDatabase/TransferText date back at least to Access 2.

Comment: Also, to add to @Remou's advice, you can use the wizard to create an import spec that you can then use with TransferSpreadsheet to insure that data type mappings are consistent.

Answer (score 2):

In Access 2007 you can use `External Data/Import/Excel`

Just follow the wizard to select the workbook, type of connection, sheet and data.
Data can be imported to a new table, appended to an existing table, or as a linked table

In Access 2003 its `File/Get External Data/Import` or `File/Get External Data/Link tables`
select file type .xls and browse to the workbook

Comment: Can you be a little more specific: version of Office, import as linked/appended/new table, how you want to trigger the import, vba code at Excel or Access end?

Comment: I am using office 2007. I want to use this to a form in access

Comment: Sorry, I don't see the need for VBA yet.  If you use `External date/Import/Excel` you have the excel data in Access as a linked table, you can then create a form that refers to this table as you see fit (refresh on demand, filter, query, whatever).  If you have other requirements that might push us toward vba please share them, so we can offer more focused advise

Answer (score 0):

if this task is something that u need to perform on a regular basis, you may want to consider creating a macro and scheduled task to perform this automatically. it is very easy to settup and I can outline procedure if need be